# Equivalence of the axiomatic and recursive definitions of the determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

In *Linear Algebra*, Lang *defines* the ***determinant*** recursively by the formula:

$$D(A) = D(A^1, \ldots, A^n) = (-1)^{i+1}a_{i1}D(A_{i1})+\cdots +(-1)^{i+n}a_{in}D(A_{in}),$$ where $A^1, \ldots,A^n$ are vectors in $K^n$ and $A_{ij}$ is the matrix created by deleting the $i$th row and $j$th column from matrix $A$.

Lang then attempts to prove that the determinant is multilinear.

Lang *defines* a function to be ***multilinear*** if for every entry $k$ of the function we have: 
$$F(A^1,\ldots ,\ B^k + C^k\ , \ldots ,\ A^n) = F(A^1,\ldots ,B^k, \ldots,A^n) + F(A^1,\ldots ,C^k,\ldots,A^n)
\\  \text{and } F(A^1\ , \ldots ,\ x\ A^k,\ldots,\ A^n)= x\ F(A^1,\ldots, A^k, \ldots , A^n)$$

His proof that the determinant is multilinear is in the linked image. It begins at: "**1.** Consider". (Note: he refers to the multilinearity condition as "property 1)".

[Lang's proof of the multilinearity of the determinant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imu4f.jpg)

My problem is that I don't understand Lang's proof. Can someone please give me an alternative proof, or explain to me precisely how his proof shows that the determinant satisfies his definition of multilinearity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine this is meant to be by induction. A linear combination of linear functions is again linear, and he's showing that every term of the sum is a linear function of the $k$-th column.

Inductively, when $j\ne k$, $\det(A_{ij})$ itself is a linear function of the $k$-th column (with its $j$-th entry removed, which is a linear operation) and $a_{ij}$ is a constant, while when $j=k$, the value $a_{ij}$ itself is evidently a linear function of the $k$-th column, while $\det(A_{ij})$ is a constant.

Comment: If Lang means by induction, then (after further examining it), it makes sense. I think what got me was that the proof is very condensed (even if Lang means by induction, it is still very condensed).